# what are windows synchronization routines other than critical_section?

Tags: winapi

I am reading through the msdn articles about windows synchronization. It is really good & thorough material. At the same time is very time consuming. I am more interested in a quick comprehensive guide on the same topic. Any pointers?

Comment: This is not a real question. Please ask something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of the concepts that I use in my native (unmanaged, Win32) application.  I've added some relevant function names between parenthesis):

- CriticalSection (InitializeCriticalSection, TryEnterCriticalSection, LeaveCriticalSection, ...)
- Mutex (CreateMutex, WaitForsingleObject, ReleaseMutex, CloseHandle, ...)
- Semaphore (CreateSemaphore, WaitForSingleObject, ReleaseSemaphore, CloseHandle, ...)
- Event (CreateEvent, SetEvent, ResetEvent, WaitForSingleObject, CloseHandle, ...)

Besides these you could also use a file to implement locking (e.g. between processes running on different machines):

- Simply create the file using CreateFile, use FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, and don't specify any of the sharing flags.
- If a process already created the file, the CreateFile will fail.
- To unlock, close the file using CloseHandle.

Comment: You can also synchronize on a thread terminating (i.e. WaitForSingleObject with a handle to a thread). Another sync primitive you left out is slim reader/writer locks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good starting point:

Synchronization Functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx